# Is Neighbor-Joining Clustering Availalble in SciPy

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I would like to use scipy.cluster.hierarchy to perform neighbor joining on a distance matrix.  However, I have been unable to locate in the documentation that this is an available option.  The reason I would like to use scipy.cluster.hierarchy specifically is because I am already using it for UPGMA clustering of the same distance matrix and I would like to keep my analysis consistent and within the same code.  Is this an available option of scipy.cluster.hierarchy? And if so what would I put in place of 'Average' in the code:

```
#Perform UPGMA hierarchical cluster with scipy.cluster.hierarchy
outDND=average(distanceMatrix)
```

Comment: I’m not sure about scipy, but have you considered using Biopython for doing this?

Comment: That will probably work, I will just have to convert my current distance matrix that is stored in a numpy array to the format used in biopython.  I was hoping to get it done without having to do that conversion.